# Import records from a flat txt file with records delimited spacing?

Tags: regex, pentaho, pentaho-design-studio

I consulted as I can configure SPOON for correct import of data, knowing that I have the data delimited by spaces.
And if it affects the import process in the penultimate record "SP_SEC" is not always a record and may be blank, affect the import?
I show the data as I have:

```
SP_NLE    SP_LIB    SP_DEP    SP_PRV    SP_DST    SP_APP    SP_APM    SP_NOM    SP_NAC    SP_SEX    SP_GRI    SP_SEC    SP_DOC
00000001    000090    70    03    04    BARDALES                                    AHUANARI                                    RENE                                   19111116    2    10         8
00000003    000001    25    01    01    MEZA                                        DE RUIZ                                     CARLOTA                                19400119    2    20    1    1
00000004    000001    25    01    01    BARDALES                                    TORRES                                      JOYCE                                  19580122    2    20    9    1
00000005    244246    25    01    02    RAMIREZ                                     RUIZ                                        FRANCISCO                              19600309    1    20    7    1
00000006    000001    25    01    01    SILVA                                       RIVERA DE RIOS                              ALICIA                                 19570310    2    20    5    1
00000008    000001    25    01    01    PACAYA                                      MANIHUARI                                   MANUEL                                 19401215    1    10    1    1
00000009    233405    25    01    02    TORRES                                      MUÑOZ                                       GLADYS                                 19650902    2    20    0    1
00000010    000508    25    01    01    OLIVOS                                      RODAS                                       BRITALDO                               19510924    1    20    3    1
00000011    000001    25    01    01    ESCUDERO                                    HERNANDEZ                                   JULIA ISABEL                           19351118    2    30         1
00000012    000001    25    01    01    YAICATE                                     TARICUARIMA                                 RICARDO                                19560118    1    20    0    1
00000013    000001    25    01    01    ESPINOZA                                    DE PINEDO                                   ALEGRIA                                19371108    2    10         1
00000014    000001    25    01    01    GARCIA                                      PINCHI                                      RICARDO                                19650315    1    30    6    1
00000015    236352    09    01    01    LAO                                         ESPINOZA                                    ALINA                                  19601217    2    30    4    1
00000017    219532    25    01    01    YAICATE                                     YAHUARCANI                                  OLGA                                   19530706    2    10    1    1
```

Please aid, which must be placed in the section "Regular Expression" and the Content tab should be placed in the section of "Separator", or other value in any other section? 
Any suggestions.

Comment: Unless you reformatted your input especially for the display in SO I would suggest that you use the step "Fixed file input" for reading your data. This way you can make sure that you handle column `SP_SEC` correctly.

Comment: Please aid, which must be placed in the section "Regular Expression" and the Content tab should be placed in the section of "Separator", or other value in any other section? Any suggestions.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this?

Comment: Hello to the community, if you already found the solution using the Navicat program is very good its ETL tool, I recommend it.